# How can I pipe svn cat output to nedit?

Tags: svn

I would like to display the results of

```
svn cat
```

in nedit.  I had originally hoped to pipe the commands output into the nedit command, but nedit doesn't support stdin pipes.

Answer (score 1):

In the top of an nedit window type your `svn cat` command, then click the 'Shell' menu, and select `Execute Command Line` .  The file still contain your command line at the top, but other than that, have the desired contents.